# Need help setting text prop of label (in a content page) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, label, master-pages

I have searched already but unable to find an answer that works. I simply want to set the text of a label that is in a content page. Obviously because the control is in a content page it has the modified client id. So I know simply ".labelName" will not work alone because the client id is for example "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_labelName".

So what is the syntax to use when the control is in a content page?

Here's what I have that is not working:

```
function intervalTypeChanged(sender, eventArgs) {

            var item = eventArgs.get_item();
            var itemText = item.get_text();
            if (itemText == "Seconds" || itemText == "Minutes" || itemText == "Hours") {
                $("#trSimpleScheduleSettings").show();                    
                $("#<%=lblSimpleDurationValueAfter.ClientID %>").text = itemText;
            }
            else {
                $("#trSimpleScheduleSettings").hide();
            }
        }
```

The table row trSimpleScheduleSettings appears but there is no text in the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$("#<%=lblSimpleDurationValueAfter.ClientID %>").text(itemText);
```

Comment: Hey Reigel, sorry, but now that I have moved the code out into a .js file it has stopped working.